# filtering dictionary keys and values in python

Tags: python, dictionary, filter

I have a list of dictionaries with the same keys and I want to filter these dictionaries by conditions that gave to me in input strings.

I have this list of dictionaries:

> dictlist:  [[{'name': '"fight club"', 'rank': 12, 'budget': 450000},
> {'name': '"Interstellar"', 'rank': 26, 'budget': 700000}], [{'name':
> '"se7en"', 'rank': 19, 'budget': 200000}, {'name': '"Hamilton"',
> 'rank': 107, 'budget': 650000}]]

and I receive the conditions from the user for example:

> SELECT (name,budget) FROM movies WHERE budget=450000

or

> SELECT (name,budget) FROM movies WHERE rank>10

or

> SELECT (name,budget,rank) FROM movies WHERE name=='fight club'

unfortunately, I couldn't code for this to filter my list of dictionaries.

I appreciate your helping me.

Comment: You have a list of lists

Comment: actually, there is 1 list that contains 2 lists of dictionaries

Comment: I am unsure, but it does look like you are trying to do database stuff in Python. I would recommend looking into MongoDB, especially since you seem to be liking the JSON/dictionary format ;)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I edited it. I tried my best.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this:

```
dictlist = [
    [{'name': '"fight club"', 'rank': 12, 'budget': 450000}, {'name': '"Interstellar"', 'rank': 26, 'budget': 700000}], 
    [{'name': '"se7en"', 'rank': 19, 'budget': 200000}, {'name': '"Hamilton"', 'rank': 107, 'budget': 650000}]
    ]

def greaterThanFilter(filterName, filterValue, dictlist):
    for i in dictlist:
        for j in i:
            if j[filterName] > filterValue:
                print(j['name'])
    
greaterThanFilter('budget', 200000, dictlist)
```

This can only check if a value is greater than another.

Modifying this code should help you. I would recommend you restructure your dictlist to look like this:

```
dictlist = [
    {'name': '"fight club"', 'rank': 12, 'budget': 450000}, 
    {'name': '"Interstellar"', 'rank': 26, 'budget': 700000}, 
    {'name': '"se7en"', 'rank': 19, 'budget': 200000}, 
    {'name': '"Hamilton"', 'rank': 107, 'budget': 650000}
    ]
```

The code to filter list the same way would look something like this:

```
def greaterThanFilter(budget, dictlist):
    return [x for x in dictlist if x['budget'] > budget]

# Output: ['"Interstellar"', '"Hamilton"']
```

Comment: You can modify the filter to do other things such as check for a matching name or a rank greater or lower than something. Plenty of room for improvement/feature implementation. You got this!

Comment: thank you so much, but unfortunately, it couldn't help me because of my fault. actually, the condition is not clear if it's greater than or less than or equal. we get the exact condition from the user and it can be for example rank>2. and because I'm creating this dictionary based on two different lists I can not change the dimension

Comment: What do you need? If you need the name to match you can use something like "    return [x for x in dictlist if x['budget'] > budget and x['name'] == "moviename here"